# Change severity of Checkstyle rule for files matching a pattern

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
  <module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="./suppressions.xml"/>
  </module>

  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
  </module>

  <module name="TreeWalker">
  ...
    <module name="JavadocMethod"/>
    <module name="JavadocType"/>
    <module name="JavadocVariable"/>
  ...
  </module>
</module>
```

And a suppressions.xml that looks like this:

```xml
<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="JavadocMethod" files="[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]java[/\\]"/>
  <suppress checks="JavadocType" files="[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]java[/\\]"/>
  <suppress checks="JavadocVariable" files="[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]java[/\\]"/>
</suppressions>
```

This has worked fine in the past, disabling the Javadoc checks for any files in the test directory.

However, now we want to show a warning for when a test file is missing javadoc, instead of ignoring it completely, but for files that aren't in the test directory, we want to still have the error severity.

I have had a try and had no luck with it.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the severity for different groups of files. (Error severity for a Javadoc issue seems pretty harsh to me, but well.)

The basic idea is to configure Checkstyle to generate both severities at the same time, then suppress the ones you don't want. In order to do this, give your checks an `id` (example for *JavadocMethod* only, for brevity):

```xml
<module name="JavadocMethod">
    <property name="id" value="jmwarn"/>
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
</module>
<module name="JavadocMethod">
    <property name="id" value="jmerr"/>
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
</module>
```

Then, in your suppressions file, you control which files get which severity:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]" id="jmerr" />
    <suppress files="[\\/]src[\\/]main[\\/]" id="jmwarn" />
</suppressions>
```